# How to migrate Xbox Minecraft to a tablet?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

My son has an Xbox 360 with the game disc for Minecraft separately. He wants to play on his tablet, but I don't know how to retrieve any info regarding Pocket Edition. **Can he sign in using the login for Xbox to play on tablet?**

Comment: No. The two versions are separate and not compatible. You need to buy the game again on the tablet of choice, and the save files can not be transferred.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the two versions are completly parralel and canot be inter-connected so you will have to buy Minecraft again. Sad, I realise, but cross-compatability is not Mojangs strong point.